# Read matrix of number in c with memory allocation

Tags: c

I have this trouble ,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
  int i;
  int j;




double** mat=malloc(3*sizeof(double*));
for(i=0;i<3;++i)
mat[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(double));




  FILE *file;
  file=fopen("pollino.txt", "r");


 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {

       if (!fscanf(file, "%d", &mat[i][j]))
           break;
      // mat[i][j] -= '0';
       printf("%d\n",mat[i][j]); 
      }


  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

This code work greatly , but now i want to do another step , that is, i want do this with the memory allocation , because i can't always to know the number of lines beforehand.
So a code for the count of the lines is:

```
int countlines(char *file)
{
FILE *fl;
char ch;
int count=0;
while((fscanf(fl,"%c",&ch))>0)
    if(ch=='\n')
    count ++;
return count;
fclose(fl);
}
```

but after this ,I don't know how to go ahead

Comment: first of all, move the closure of the file before the return because as currently standing, your code never closes the file.

Comment: and  You have forgotten to open the file.

Comment: The best way would be to also modify the input text file and the first line should contain the number of rows and the number of columns (or a single value if the matrix is square), then the matrix data. that would get you rid of `countlines`. Is that possible?

Comment: @the paramagnetic croissant , done !